# Difference in using DB links in SQL Server 2017 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I have two SQL Server environments:

1. SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) WITH replication to another MS Server node (master + slave architecture)
2. SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)

There is same DbLink from these servers to Firebird DB. Test connection returns "OK".

When I call

```
select top 10 * from PROD_R...face_accs
```

on the 1st environment I receive Error

> SQL Server Database Error: The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PROD_R" does not contain the table "face_accs" The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.`,

but it works fine on the 2nd environment. Also If I call this query via `OPENQUERY` on the 1st environment it works too.

Does query like «from PROD_R...face_accs» not work anymore on SQL Server 2017?

Comment: In four part name, I think you are missing database name. you might need to mention it to check for table existance check

Comment: I tries to use `a_data` (it is db name in firebird) in `select top 10 * from PROD_R.a_data.face_accs`, but it doesn't help. I executed this query in a lot of variants.